# Swift ForEach relocate with onDrag&onDrop

Tags: swift, swiftui, foreach

I want to create simple todo list application. I have two questions.

Here is my code:

Model and ViewModel

```
struct TaskModel: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let title: String
}

class TaskViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks = [TaskModel]()
    
    init() {
        getTasks()
    }
    
    func getTasks() {
        let newTasks = [
            TaskModel(title: "0 task"),
            TaskModel(title: "1 task"),
            TaskModel(title: "2 task"),
            TaskModel(title: "3 task"),
            TaskModel(title: "4 task"),
            TaskModel(title: "5 task"),
            TaskModel(title: "6 task"),
            TaskModel(title: "7 task"),
            TaskModel(title: "8 task"),
            TaskModel(title: "9 task"),
        ]
        tasks.append(contentsOf: newTasks)
    }
    
}
```

View:

```
struct onDropView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = TaskViewModel()
    
    @State private var dragging: TaskModel?
    @State private var changedView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello")
            
            ForEach(vm.tasks) { task in
                TaskCellView(task: task)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .background(dragging?.id == task.id && changedView ? .blue : .white)
                    .opacity(dragging?.id == task.id && changedView ? 0.01 : 1) // work
                    .onDrag {
                        self.dragging = task
                        changedView = false
                        return NSItemProvider(object: String(task.id) as NSString)
                    }
                    .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DragDelegate(task: task,
                                                                      tasks: $vm.tasks,
                                                                      draggedTask: $dragging,
                                                                      changeView: $changedView))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And delegate function:

```
struct DragDelegate: DropDelegate {
    let task: TaskModel
    
    @Binding var tasks: [TaskModel]
    @Binding var draggedTask: TaskModel?
    @Binding var changeView: Bool
    
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        if draggedTask == nil { draggedTask = task }
        
        changeView = true
        
        if task != draggedTask {
            guard
                let current = draggedTask,
                let from = tasks.firstIndex(of: current),
                let to = tasks.firstIndex(of: task)
            else { return }
            
            if tasks[to].id != current.id {
                tasks.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: from), toOffset: (to > from) ? to + 1 : to )
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        return DropProposal(operation: .move)
    }
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        self.changeView = false
        self.draggedTask = nil
        return true
    }
    
    
}
```

1. I have created a ForEach loop and I have a strange problem. When opacity is 0 my task disappears when dropped.

`.opacity(dragging?.id == task.id && changedView ? 0 : 1) // doesn't work`

But after changing the opacity from: 0 to: 0.01, everything works fine. Task doesn't disappear when dropped.

`.opacity(dragging?.id == task.id && changedView ? 0.01 : 1) // work`

What is causing it and how to fix it?

2. The currently dragged task decreases. I want the task size to stay the same while dragging
   I tried with the overlay. But the view freezes until I press another task.

Thank you

Comment: If you use List you get drag and drop moves for free, e.g. `List($items, editActions: [EditActions.all]) { $item in`.

Comment: I suggest checking out the alternative [`onDrop(of:isTargeted:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ondrop(of:istargeted:perform:)-982eu) modifier instead, that doesn't require the use of a cumbersome `DropDelegate`.